# C# : Download .jpg from .ashx site

Tags: c#, ashx

I'm currently trying to download an image from a site that uses a .ashx to manage uploaded images. The site is "UploadHandler.ashx" and takes parameters such as width, height and image id. When I go there in my browser it automatically downloads the picture for me. But when I try to download it using HttpWebRequest and cookies it gives me an image that is 1kb and if I change it into a .txt it's HTML that says that the object has been moved and refers me to the login page.

My current code for downloading:

```
void DownloadImage(string onlinepath, string localpath)
    {
        Stream remoteStream = null;
        Stream localStream = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(onlinepath);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.CookieContainer = cookie;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                delegate (
                    object sender,
                    X509Certificate certificate,
                    X509Chain chain,
                    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                {
                    return true;
                };
            if (request != null)
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                    localStream = File.Create(localpath);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;

                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null) response.Close();
            if (remoteStream != null) remoteStream.Close();
            if (localStream != null) localStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Current output in .txt format:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Login/Index">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Set `AllowAutoRedirect` to `true`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler that downloads an HTML of the login page

Comment: Then your browser must be doing more than just requesting the file (e.g. send authentication cookies or similar).

Comment: what status code are ytou getting? it seems to me that you arent authorized.

Comment: Use Fiddler and compare the requests your browser is sending to the requests your program is sending. Make sure you've got all the correct headers/cookies.

Comment: you don't show where your "cookie" object comes from. Is anything in it? You'd need the login cookies in the container before your request.

Comment: I use the same cookie container that I used with a previous web request and that is authenticated but this request is not authenticated. Can't really figure out why though